# Here , I am trying to build a new dataframe from an existing dataframe by selecting specific rows based on indexes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdQXc.png)I Have a list fp_index which contains certain indexes . Now i want to create a dataframe which will be having rows from dataframe X_test. But the new dataframe will have only the rows corresponding to the indexes in fp_index. I have tried two ways, but the issue i am facing in my fp_index is of length 2460.

But the new df gets created with 790 rows, it should be of 2460 rows as i am giving 2460 indexes.

print(len(fp_index)) #o/p 2460

X_test_fp = pd.DataFrame(columns=X_test.columns)

for i in fp_index :

```
X_test_fp = X_test_fp.append(X_test.filter(items=[i], axis=0))
```

print(len(X_test_fp)) #o/p 790

Filter_df  = X_test[X_test.index.isin(fp_index)]
print(len(Filter_df)) #o/p 790

Comment: You can directly give the indeces to the dataframe: `new_df = pd.DataFrame(old_df.iloc[fp_index])`

Comment: Thanks a lot , this one worked. Any idea what might be wrong in the above code which I shared...